# User control menu link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a menu in a user control but the link is not working. It is disabled. please help me to fix.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="menu.ascx.cs" Inherits="menu" %>

<div class="h_mnu_01"> 
<ul> 
<li>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink></li>

</ul>
</div>

<code>
<style type="text/css">

.h_mnu_01{
width: 100%;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
text-decoration: none;
  }

 .h_mnu_01 ul{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
width: 100%;
background: #000000;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-right-width: 0;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-left-width: 0;
border-top-style: solid;
border-right-style: solid;
border-bottom-style: solid;
border-left-style: solid;
border-top-color: #000000;
border-right-color: #000000;
border-bottom-color: #000000;
border-left-color: #000000
  }

 .h_mnu_01 ul li{
   display: inline;
 }

 .h_mnu_01 ul li a{
float: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
padding: 5px 11px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-color: #000000;
 }
```

.h_mnu_01 ul li a:visited
    {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    }

.h_mnu_01 ul li a:hover, .h_mnu_01 ul li .selected
    {
    color: #FFFF00 !important;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: #008000;
    }

```
</style>
```

Comment: "Is not working" is not a problem/question

Comment: You should provide more information about the issue, like exception, http error code! Yelling for help it's not polite, and don't help us to help you.

Comment: I am not able click on the link to navigate to another page. The link is not clickable.

Comment: Check if any code is modifying the link from code-behind or javascript. Also, note your css styles.

Comment: The problem is with the css. when I removed css it worked. I can't find problem in the css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is clickable, but you changed it's style to show as plain text instead of hyperlink:

```
.h_mnu_01 ul li a{
    float: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 11px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right-width: 1px;
    border-right-style: solid;
    border-right-color: #000000;
}
```

Remove **text-decoration: none;** from this style. It should work.